# Reliable, Simple Transfer of Really Large Files?

Tags: uti, file-transfer, ftp

I want to be able to move really large video files (think 60 - 90 GB) between Macs in different cities on a closed network. I'd like to be able to go point to point, so no single-server or cloud-based solutions. Because the pipe between locations isn't huge, the files may take hours to transfer. I want a solution that won't just stop if there is an intermittent network error, or even an unexpected reboot. The interface should also be simple; something like a folder for each destination that a user can drag and drop to.

Nice to have would be the ability to monitor and pause a delivery on the receiving end, so if two transfers get started at the same time you don't have to wait forever for either to finish.

I know there are some really expensive solutions. I think there are some FTP clients that  come close. Anyone know something affordable that would meet the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

[Transmit](https://www.panic.com/transmit/) is my personal favorite but [Fetch](http://fetchsoftworks.com/store) also does the trick you ask.

---

iCloud will help you locate the IP of the remote machine and screen share if needed and is much simpler than getting a free DNS software solution to locate the IP of the other endpoint (assuming you have dynamic IP address or are behind a NAT router on either end of the transfer).